# Where is images in registry:2

Tags: docker-registry

Where is images in registry:2

If I exec into the container running the registry:

```
 docker exec -it kind-registry sh
```

Do you know where I can see a list of images - to be able to list and delete.

Comment: you want to see the image layer or list what is stored in the registry?

Comment: To be able to manage images, list delete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [API](https://docs.docker.com/registry/spec/api/#listing-repositories) to curl the private registry. Further reading at the [Docker Forum](https://forums.docker.com/t/docker-private-registry-how-to-list-all-images/21136).

```
curl http://my.registry.com/v2/_catalog
```

Should work.